# How do I set the column of a javafx table to the hashmap of a object?

Tags: java

I am trying to set 2 columns of a `javafx` table to the `Hashmap` key and value of an Object.

**Table Declaration:**

[image]

**Setting column to use hashmap values:**

[image]

Comment: I don't think I clearly understood your problem. can you clarify the question a bit? also as far as I know the type of data you put in a TableView and the first generic type of the columns have to be the same.

Comment: Alright so i want to set the 2 columns of the table view to the data thats in the hashmap so the first column would be the key and the second would be the value associated with that key. The problem is the hashmap is in the object(DepartmentDTO).

Comment: Please don't post images of code, [edit] the code into your question instead.

Comment: I tried to do that initially but the site wasnt allowing me to type the code there and kept giving me errors thats why i uploaded the photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so first declare your TableView Like this:

```
TableView<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> tblNetworkEngineering;
```

Your TableColumn code should work fine as is.

Then populate the table using this code:

```
tblNetworkEngineering.getItems().setAll(departmentDTO.getMap().entrySet());
```

Comment: This seems to only add the last hashmap key and value pair to the table.

Comment: this should work as expected. check to see if your map has all the data.

Comment: Ohhh it seems that if the data isnt different then it only adds the last instance so in my test map i changed the data and it works perfectly. Thanks alot man